# Xamarin.iOS, app crashes before it's even ran on the phone

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

when launching an app on the iOS 10 device, the app never gets launched, it just terminates. I have no logs on the device nor in the debug window of Visual Studio, I just see

> Launching 'App1' on 'iPhone'...
>
> The app has been terminated.

This is the only output from the debug window.

As I said, no logs no nothing.. Just starts launching and all of a sudden it fails.

Everything works properly on iOS 10 emulators

Comment: What about the call stack window in VS or even the Output window in VS, this will definitively have something!

Comment: is working on simulator ?

Comment: Yes, it's working on simulator as expected

Comment: What's the Linker set to do? Does it work when you link all assemblies?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description I'm fairly certain that you're hitting the new, iOS10 requirement, for application to state their required privacy permissions in their `Info.plist`.

Apple **requires** this for all applications compiled against the iOS10 SDK - otherwise iOS **crash** the app (yes, I think a popup would have been nicer to developers). Like most sandbox restrictions this is **not** enforced on the iOS simulator - but only on devices.

Speaking of devices you should have both logs and a crash report to give you more details about what's going on (including what key is missing and provoked the crash). Open Xcode (on your Mac) and look for them.

There's more information in the XI 10.0 [release notes](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/ios/xamarin.ios_10/xamarin.ios_10.0/).

Answer (score 0):

When I experienced this, I had success by bumping up the base version of the app, clean the project and rebuild.